# Clustered indexes versus non-clustered indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, indexes

I am in charge of a smaller DB 300+ hundred megs 100'ish tables about 45 users hit it throughout the work day. Mostly reads, but a fair number of updates and inserts. I have been slowing learning the structure of the DB in order to get some performance out of it. I have heard that taking a look at indexes is a good place to start. All most all of the indexes for the tables of said DB are clustered, a few of them are non-clustered.

Is there any speed advantage over clustered vs non-clustered? I have a maintenance plan (yes yes, I know) that re-orgs and rebuild the indexes nightly before diff backups, is this good enough for now, until I get a better grip on index formation and utilization?

Is/are there (a) script(s) that will help me view 'performance' of the various indexes?
Just how big of can of worms did I get my self into?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A clustered index determines the physical order of data in a table and is particularly efficient on columns that are often searched for ranges of values. They are also efficient for finding a specific row when the indexed value is unique.

Normally (there are exceptions), the clustered index should be on a column that increases monotonically - such as an identity column, or some other column where the value is increasing - and is unique. In many cases, the primary key is the ideal column for a clustered index (but don't put a clustered index on a uniqueidentifier/GUID column.)

From this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

> Before creating clustered indexes,
>   understand how your data will be
>   accessed. Consider using a clustered
>   index for:
>
> - Columns that contain a large number of distinct values.
> - Queries that return a range of values using operators such as
>     BETWEEN, >, >=, <, and <=.
> - Columns that are accessed sequentially.
> - Queries that return large result sets.
> - Columns that are frequently accessed by queries involving join or GROUP BY
>     clauses; typically these are foreign
>     key columns. An index on the column(s)
>     specified in the ORDER BY or GROUP BY
>     clause eliminates the need for SQL
>     Server to sort the data because the
>     rows are already sorted. This improves
>     query performance.
> - OLTP-type applications where very fast single row lookup is required,
>     typically by means of the primary key.
>     Create a clustered index on the
>     primary key.
>
> Clustered indexes are not a good
>   choice for:
>
> - Columns that undergo frequent changes: This results in the entire
>     row moving (because SQL Server must
>     keep the data values of a row in
>     physical order). This is an important
>     consideration in high-volume
>     transaction processing systems where
>     data tends to be volatile.
> - Wide keys: The key values from the clustered index are used by all
>     nonclustered indexes as lookup keys
>     and therefore are stored in each
>     nonclustered index leaf entry.

SQLServerpedia.com has some nice articles/tutorials for index tuning: [Index Related DMV Queries](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Index_Related_DMV_Queries) and [Using the Right Indexes for Optimal Performance](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_the_Right_Indexes_for_Optimal_Performance).

Comment: Thanks for clearing away some of the smoke. Thanks for the two links also.

Answer (score 5):

I've read that it's very good practice to use a surrogate key & use a clustered index on that column. Typically, this will be an int column that will auto-increment (IDENTITY), or a uniqueidentifier (make it a **sequential GUID** to avoid performance issues later on!).

In doing so, your queries will do JOINs on those surrogate keys across tables, giving you performance & scalability.

As far as other (non-clustered) indexes, that choice depends on how your customers use your application. Too many indexes spells disaster for inserts/updates. Insufficient indexes slow down reads. You'll need to find a balance b/w the two. Columns that are used in conjunction with searches are logical candidates for indexing, including composite (multi-column) indexes (mind your column order, in that case).

If you want to get fancy, have a separate OLAP database for reporting on historical data.